# surround system + hard drive being too close = death

Tags: windows-7, audio, external-hard-drive, surround-sound

I bought a sound system of ~1000 watts for my HTPC and I was wondering:

how close should my computer and/or hard drives be from it in order to prevent sound and/or magnetic damage?

Thanks

Also please provide me some proof or your background of your awesome knowledge :)

---

update: it's my HTPC (duh :p)  and my external hard drive lives in the same room as the system

Comment: I suspect your neighbours would complain before your HDD gets damaged. Are you worried about damage from sound, or the actual vibration of the speakers? I wouldn't worry about magnetic damage, computers are fairly well shielded

Comment: Just a note, vibration on HDD is also can be bad. And vibration can be caused by your speaker vibration, or simple noise (loud noise). This is a video of someone demonstrating that screaming at your HDD (in a data center) actually cause data transfer spike -> www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDacjrSCeq4 

This may not apply too much to you, but something for you to consider as loud noise / vibration can cause the HDD to halt temporarily when it detected vibration/misalignment when accessing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only component that you really have much to worry about is a hard drive. If you have an SSD the point is moot.

Otherwise, a foot would be more than enough space (This was about average for poorly shielded speakers and PCs / CRT monitors). Although, with decent speakers I have seen more than a few speakers sitting *on* the PC and there has been no detrimental effects.

That said, the PC and the speakers should be shielded. At 1000 watts, it probably is not a cheap system that did not shield properly.

The most probable, least shielded item would be the sub-woofer, so keep that as far away as possible.

Comment: it's denon if that helps... what about my external hard drive does that get shielding?

Answer (score 0):

You should have no issues with them right next to each other.  All your devices are well shielded.  In addition to that, home based electrical devices do not typically generate a large or powerful magnetic field.  As for proof, well...  There are plenty of HTPC, DVRs, etc that are more than 1000 watts that have hard drives *inside* them.

As for sound, I wouldnt worry.  I have never heard a hard drive die by sound vibrations.

I have a 1500 watt amp sitting on top of my HTPC for several years now with no issues.